# how to improve the performance of creating tables in sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I use python & sqlite3 to do something, and I need to create lots of table in sqlte3. All the tables have the same schema like this:

```
ID |    AA BB CC DD EE FF GG
1      a  b  c  d  e  f  g
.      ....................
.      ....................
.      ....................
2000   ....................


for i in stl_lines[1:]:
    line = i.split(' ')
    sql = "CREATE TABLE '%06d'" \
                       "(A  INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL," \
                       " B INTEGER NOT NULL," \
                       " C INTEGER NOT NULL," \
                       " D INTEGER NOT NULL," \
                       " E INTEGER NOT NULL," \
                       " F REAL    NOT NULL," \
                       " G INTEGER NOT NULL," \
                       "PRIMARY KEY(DATE))" % (int(line[0]))
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

When I run this code, I found that I almost need 1~2s to create one table, and I have more than 2000 tables, it's cost me about 3000s to create the db, this cost is unacceptable.
How can I improve the speed of creating tables, or do you have any advice about designing the database?
Thanks!

---

Finally, I solved the problem by the helping of **CL.**. Now I can create 2000 tables in 2s! Thanks him/her very much.

This is my new code:

```
db = sqlite3.connect(DB_FILE)
db.isolation_level = None
cursor.execute('BEGIN ')
for i in stock_tables:
    cursor.execute(i)
cursor.execute('COMMIT ')
db.isolation_level = ''
```

Comment: I think the problem here is that sqlite databases are not designed to handle that many tables in the first place. I suggest you rethink your data structures so that you have less tables with more flexible columns.

Comment: Why do you need 2000+ tables? Why are you doing it so often that this is an issue? Why are you naming your columns things like `A` or `B`? Do you know who is going to have to maintain this code, and if so how much do you hate them?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the formal code in my project.I just changed the columns' names for the easy way to read.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is Python; it tries to be smart and automatically commits a transaction for every CREATE TABLE statement ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-controlling-transactions)).

You want to use a single transaction instead.
Set [`isolation_level`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.isolation_level) to `None`, and execute BEGIN/COMMIT once around all your statements.